# Conflicting mysql queries in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm getting a conflict error in using two mysql queries. I want to get two tables from database using join syntax and everything goes fine, until I put an outer function in where clause which returns an ID from another model. This makes a conflict in query.

**This is my first and MAIN model function:**

```
function get_festival_data($options = array())
{
    // Qualification
    if(isset($options['festival_Id']))
        $this->db->where('md_festivals.festival_Id', $options['festival_Id']);

    if(isset($options['festival_Status']))
        $this->db->where('festival_Status', $options['festival_Status']);

    $this->db->where('lang_Id', currentLanguageID());

    $this->db->from('md_festivals');

    $this->db->join('md_festival_details', 'md_festival_details.festival_Id = md_festivals.festival_Id');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if(isset($options['festival_Id']) return $query->row(0);

    return $query->result();
}
```

This is a helper to make a global function:

```
function currentLanguageID()
{

    $language = get_instance()->languages_model->get_language_data
    (
        array(
            'lang_Abbr' => config('language_abbr')
        )
    );

    return $language->lang_Id;
}
```

**Which nicely returns the ID**

and this is the other model function:

```
function get_language_data($options = array())
{
    // Qualification
    if(isset($options['lang_Id']))
        $this->db->where('lang_Id', $options['lang_Id']);

    if(isset($options['lang_Abbr']))
        $this->db->where('lang_Abbr', $options['lang_Abbr']);

    $query = $this->db->get('md_languages');

    if(isset($options['lang_Id']) || isset($options['lang_Abbr']))
        return $query->row(0);

    return $query->result();
}
```

and the following is the conflict and the error I'm getting:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'md_festivals.festival_Id' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT * FROM `md_languages` WHERE `md_festivals`.`festival_Id` = '6'
>   AND `festival_Status` = 1 AND `lang_Abbr` = 'fa'
>
> Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/aksineh/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

It puts both models' where clauses inside each other and makes a conflict!!

Comment: You select from `md_languages` table, how can you get field from `md_festivals` table?

Comment: I want to get the ID from `md_languages` tables (globally, everywhere I want) and put it inside the functions in other models. Right now, my main query is from `md_festivals` and not the `md_languages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved by changing the order in where clauses. I brought the `$this->db->where('lang_Id', currentLanguageID());` where clause to the beginning of the function:

```
function get_festival_data($options = array())
{
    // Qualification

    $this->db->where('lang_Id', currentLanguageID());


    if(isset($options['festival_Id']))
        $this->db->where('md_festivals.festival_Id', $options['festival_Id']);

    if(isset($options['festival_Status']))
        $this->db->where('festival_Status', $options['festival_Status']);

    $this->db->from('md_festivals');

    $this->db->join('md_festival_details', 'md_festival_details.festival_Id = md_festivals.festival_Id');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if(isset($options['festival_Id']) return $query->row(0);

    return $query->result();
}
```